# Xamarin Android ImageView Transition

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-transitions

I am trying to transition an ImageView from an item within my RecyclerView inside a fragment to an Activity.  I have declared the following in my

> styles.xml

```
<!-- enable window content transitions -->
<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>

<!-- specify enter and exit transitions -->
<!-- options are: explode, slide, fade -->
<item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/change_image_transform</item>
<item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/change_image_transform</item>

<!-- specify shared element transitions -->
<item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">
  @transition/change_image_transform
</item>
<item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">
  @transition/change_image_transform
</item>
```

Then in my

> Recyclerview Adapter

I am starting the activity using

```
if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
{ 
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.MakeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity)Context, pec.View, "profile");
    Context.StartActivity(intent, options.ToBundle());
}
```

I have defined both ImageViews with the

> transitionName="profile"

and also have a

> transition/change_image_transform.xml

that looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <changeImageTransform/>
</transitionSet>
```

There are no errors, just no transition takes place between my item in the recyclerview and the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using the `MakeSceneTransitionAnimation` you do not need to design the transition in the xml file. Just set `<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>` is enough.

When you do the imageview transition you should make sure the transition name is same.

I have a [demo](https://github.com/mikexxma/SearchView_With_ProgressBarDemo/tree/master/AndroidTransitionDemo) it should be helpful for you, the view transition from MainActivity to Activity1.
You can refer to the project and find the solution.

[image]

Comment: Does the image have to be fixed on both ImageViews?  I am loading the activity from a RecyclerView so each row will have a different image and I want to pass that across to the activity.

Comment: @Carl Image do not need to fixed on both imageviews. Use the `Pair` to defined the muti imageview with same transition name. You can put a id in the `intent` when the `DetialActivity` on create you can receive the id and set the different image in the`'ImageView` of `DetialActivity`

Comment: Found the issue, I was using ActivityOptionsCompat, now I've changed it to ActivityOptions everything is working.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: can i do this from activity to fragment?